# AdMob won't work on my app - Says I must have an AdActivity declared (I already do!!)

Tags: admob

Whenever I test the AdMob thingy I've included in my project, rather than an advert I get:
"You must have an adactivity declared in androidmanifest.xml with configChanges".

After some extensive research I keep getting the same answers - Build your app for version 3.2 or higher.
Well... NO. I won't - That's a STUPID solution.

"We don't have enough food to eat tonight, should I get some more?"
"Nah, you should just chop off your arms, then you wont be able to eat the food anyway."

Thats the logic I'm seeing.

Can anyone tell me how to put adverts on Apps for 1.6+?
Cheers

Answer (score 2):

So even if you set `target=android-13` or higher in your `project.properties` file, you can still actually build your apps on all Android devices down to 1.5 as long as you use `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3"/>` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Referenced from [here](http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/11/migrating-to-v431-of-admob-sdk-for.html).

Comment: Yep, I have both of those settings in place - yet when I load up the emulator it gives me the error message (as above): "You must have AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml with configChanges."
EDIT
It seems I had all the ingredients in place at one point, just never all at the same time.
Cheers

Comment: OK I've had the emulator running for about 20 minutes now and no advert has shown up...  I had assumed that because no error message was visible an ad would load.  I am aware that the first time takes a little longer, but I was led to believe this was more of a 3 minute wait and not a 20 minute...?

Answer (score 1):

Here may be this will help

first you should have internet user permission set in your manifest like this :

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

then declare your ad activity in manifest like this :

```
    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

also plz update your admob sdk to latest one as current one is "V-6.3.0".

while testing your app add this line to your admob view

```
     ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"
```

and this should work for any version...